# rails call to another server gives cross origin issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cross-domain

For a rails project there are api call on completely  different server.

To make those calls when I try from java script using ajax, its gives me cross origin issue.

Do I need to first go to controller & than make those api calls or there is some other way to call from Javascript?

(I know that I should share some code or my efforts but don't think that there is anything to share )

Comment: While you wait for others to answer please see what is CORS and what causes it and how to resolve it.I hope you can answer it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without code examples, but I think you could proxy it.
So you can send ajax request to your controller which returns formatted response from the external resource.

You can also try to do it via middleware, this is [helpful gem](https://github.com/zerowidth/rack-streaming-proxy)